# Alternatives for long .when().then().when().then().otherwise() chains

Tags: python-polars

Are there some clever alternatives writing long when().then().otherwise() chains without hardcoding the values, see the example below:

Let's say we have the following dataframe

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "Market":["AT", "AT", "DE", "DE", "CA", "DE", "UK", "US"],
        "Number of Days":[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1],
        
    }
)
```

User defines some conditions as a dictionary for different countries

```
params = {
    "AT":{"Value": 1},
    "DE":{"Value": 2},
    "CA":{"Value": 3},
    "UK":{"Value": 1},
    "US":{"Value": 2}
}
```

Then I hard-code the countries and use the countries in the Polars .with_columns() as below:

```
(
    df
    .with_columns(
        [
            pl.when(pl.col("Market") == "AT").then(pl.col("Number of Days") + params["AT"]["Value"])
            .when(pl.col("Market") == "DE").then(pl.col("Number of Days") + params["DE"]["Value"])
            .when(pl.col("Market") == "CA").then(pl.col("Number of Days") + params["CA"]["Value"])
            .when(pl.col("Market") == "UK").then(pl.col("Number of Days") + params["UK"]["Value"])
            .when(pl.col("Market") == "US").then(pl.col("Number of Days") + params["US"]["Value"])
            .otherwise(None)
            .alias("New Column")
        ]
    )
)
```

Is there a way for me not to hard-code the countries in .with_columns, but somehow loop through the dictionary and create expression based on the values provided?¨

I tried the below but it says I have duplicate column names.

```
exprs = []
for market, data in params.items():
    condition = (pl.col("Market") == market)
    result = (pl.col("Number of Days") + data["Value"])
    expr = pl.when(condition).then(result)
    exprs.append(expr)

df.with_columns(exprs)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`map_dict`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.map_dict.html#polars.Expr.map_dict)

```
(
    df
        .with_columns((
            pl.col("Number of Days") + 
            pl.col("Market")
                .map_dict({x:y['Value'] for x,y in params.items()})
            )
            .alias("New Column")
        )
)
```

Alternatively you can make params its own df and then join them. `map_dict` works by converting your dict into a df and then joining them but depending on where your params are coming from for real this might be preferred.

```
paramsdf = pl.DataFrame({'Market':params.keys(), 
                         'Value':[x['Value'] for x in params.values()]})
(
    df.join(paramsdf, on="Market")
        .with_columns((pl.col("Number of Days")+ pl.col("Value")).alias("New Column"))
        .drop("Value")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop is creating separate `pl.when()` objects, hence the duplicates error.

You can use [`pl.coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars-coalesce) to create a single column from them.

```py
df.with_columns(pl.coalesce(exprs))
```

```py
shape: (8, 2)
┌────────┬────────────────┐
│ Market ┆ Number of Days │
│ ---    ┆ ---            │
│ str    ┆ i64            │
╞════════╪════════════════╡
│ AT     ┆ 2              │
│ AT     ┆ 3              │
│ DE     ┆ 5              │
│ DE     ┆ 6              │
│ CA     ┆ 6              │
│ DE     ┆ 6              │
│ UK     ┆ 3              │
│ US     ┆ 3              │
└────────┴────────────────┘
```

Another option is to reshape the dict and use [`.replace`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.replace.html) to insert the values.

```py
>>> { key: value["Value"] for key, value in params.items() }
{'AT': 1, 'DE': 2, 'CA': 3, 'UK': 1, 'US': 2}
```

```py
market_values = { 
   key: value["Value"] for key, value in params.items() 
}

df.with_columns(
   pl.col("Number of Days") + pl.col("Market").replace(market_values, return_dtype=pl.Int64)
)
```

```py
shape: (8, 2)
┌────────┬────────────────┐
│ Market ┆ Number of Days │
│ ---    ┆ ---            │
│ str    ┆ i64            │
╞════════╪════════════════╡
│ AT     ┆ 2              │
│ AT     ┆ 3              │
│ DE     ┆ 5              │
│ DE     ┆ 6              │
│ CA     ┆ 6              │
│ DE     ┆ 6              │
│ UK     ┆ 3              │
│ US     ┆ 3              │
└────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: I like your `expr = pl.when(False).then(None)` trick to start the for loop.